# How to calculate the limit of $ x^{\alpha - 1}e^{-\frac{x}{2}} $ as $ x $ tends to positive infinity?

Tags: limits

Where $ \alpha $ is a real number s.t. $ \alpha > 0 $. Also, we've only today gone over Taylor series, and this limit was given by the professor as an assignment in a prior lecture, so I'd prefer to see an answer that doesn't involve Taylor series.

Comment: Hint: consider the Taylor series of $e^{x/2}$.

Comment: We've only today gone over Taylor series, but the professor assigned this limit as an assignment in a prior lecture, so I don't think I need the Taylor series to derive the answer. Of course, I'm not saying that you can't do it that way, I'd just prefer another more elementary derivation.

Comment: It's pretty difficult to answer if it is not clear which techniques are and are not allowed. It's fine if you don't want to use Taylor series, but please edit your post to make this clear. [Context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960) matters.

Comment: If you're not allowed to use Taylor series, then consider that $$x^{\alpha - 1}e^{-x/2}=\exp\left((\alpha-1)\log x - \frac{x}{2}\right) \, .$$Are you able to argue that $\log x$ will grow more slowly than $\dfrac{x}{2} \, ?$

Comment: Would it be enough to show that the limit of (log(x) / (x / 2)) = 0, to conclude that log(x) will grow more slowly than (x / 2)?

Comment: Not quite. If
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0
$$
then this does not imply that 
$$
\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)-g(x)=-\infty \, .
$$
Consider the case $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{x}$ and $g(x)=\dfrac{1}{x}+1$. Here, we need to show that
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty}\left((\alpha-1)\log x-\frac{x}{2}\right)=-\infty \, .
$$
Simply showing that
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{(\alpha-1)\log x}{x/2}=0
$$
is not enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by L'Hopital's rule, which gives the answer efficiently, but doesn't give much, if any, insight.

Thus: First $x^{\alpha-1} e^{-x/2} \le x^{n-1} e^{-x/2}$ where $n = \lceil\alpha\rceil$ is the least integer that is not less than $\alpha.$ So if you can show that $x^{n-1} e^{-x/2}\to0$ as $x\to+\infty$ then the same is true of the function you asked about.

In the fraction $\dfrac{x^{n-1}}{e^{x/2}},$ iteration of differentiation of the numerator ultimately reduces it to $0$ while the denominator remains positive no matter how many times you differentiate it.

But there is also a way that enables you to *understand* why the limit must be $0.$ It must be $0$ if, every time $x$ is incremented by $2,$ the expression $x^{n-1} e^{-x/2}$ becomes less than half as big as it was. And that must happen because the denominator gets multiplied by $e>2.7$ while the numerator gets multiplied only by $\big((x+2)/x\big)^{n-1},$ which approaches $1$ as $x\to+\infty.$

Comment: Michael, I really like the emphasis you place on intuitive understanding in your posts. Too many mathematicians focus exclusively on rigour.

Comment: @Joe : Thank you. $\qquad$